# Stripe source creation is failing

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm seeing an odd error associated with Stripe in that I'm unable to create sources with my live API keys.

1. Upon customer creation in my application, a customer gets created on Stripe (i.e. live API keys are working)
2. When using the **test** Stripe API keys, I'm able to add cards and do charges
3. When I use my **live** API keys on my site, the customer.sources.create() call fails even though I'm passing a valid source into the function.

   ```
    stripe_customer_id = cus_IoiFADFAADFASDF (made up value for this post, but is a valid one in my environment that has been generated by Stripe)

    source = src_1ILfdf3asdfasdfasdfadsf (made up value for this post, but is a valid one in my environment that has been generated by Stripe)

    customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id)

    stripe_card_response = customer.sources.create(source=source) #THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE THAT FAILS
   ```

I've confirmed that the stripe_customer_id and source variables that I'm passing into these functions are populated. They are populated with values sent to me from Stripe.

Unfortunately, Stripe doesn't return any discernable errors. In other words, as I go through the following exceptions in my code, only the last one is hit, which is a generic catch all.

```
except stripe.error.CardError as e:
except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
except Exception as e: #this is where the error falls as it doesn't relate to any of the others
```

The 500 error returns the following

```
    raise AttributeError(*err.args)
AttributeError: sources
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you retrieve a customer its [sources aren't returned by default](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=python#customer_object-sources).

If you expand the request on retrieving the customer, your code should work as expected:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id,
  expand=['sources']
)

stripe_card_response = customer.sources.create(source=source)
```

The "retrieve, mutate in place and then save" pattern is one that Stripe is moving away from in favour of client services. Instead you could do the following which means you don't need to retrieve the customer and save you from having to expand the `sources`:

```
source = stripe.Customer.create_source(
  stripe_customer_id,
  source=source
)
```

Comment: missing a comma after stripe_customer_id ?

Comment: Oops, thanks for the catch!